# Integration and Parallel Computing in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parallelization

In mathematica, how would I use parallel computing (or paralleltable) to compute the integrals of $x^2$, $x$, $3x$ from $x=0$ to $10$ just like in the first answer of https://superuser.com/questions/315337/how-to-make-commands-in-mathematica-8-use-all-cores? After entering the three functions into a table, I'm not sure how to tell Mathematica to integrate the functions. I understand that parallel computing is not the most efficient method, but once I realize how to do this, I can extend it to a much more complicated series of functions.

The motivation of this question is that I have a complicated function (see below) that takes a very, very long time to integrate (after two hours, the function still had not integrated). I'm hoping to break this function up into a group of slightly less complicated functions and utilize parallel computing to compute the integrals.

If I can't do this, is there a way to let mathematica use all four cores on my computer to compute the integral, but not using parallel computing?

Thank you.

```
(Sin[q - x] ((0.476497 - 0.401956 I) - (0.476497 + 0.598044 I) Tanh[
        0.933024 (q - x)]) + 
   Cos[q - x] ((0.401956 + 0.504489 I) + (0.598044 + 0.504489 I) Tanh[
        1.06598 (q - x)])) (Sin[
     q + x] ((0.476497 - 0.401956 I) - (0.476497 - 0.598044 I) Tanh[
        0.933024 (q + x)]) + 
   Cos[q + x] ((0.401956 - 0.504489 I) + (0.598044 + 0.504489 I) Tanh[
        1.06598 (q + x)]))
```

Note: I plan to integrate x between -10 and 10 where p and q are arbitrary variables so I can then plot the result as a contour map.

Comment: maybe a duplicate with http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1620/parallelizing-numerical-integration-in-mathematica

Comment: Can I do numerical integration when p and q are arbitrary variables?

Comment: Where is p? I only see q.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `NIntegrate`, you can get a significant speed-up using the method option

```
Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}
```

If you add this to your calculation, the integrand can be used as written in your question without modification, and it can be dropped right into the `Plot` as well:

```
Plot[Re[
      NIntegrate[
       (Sin[q - x] ((0.476497 - 
            0.401956 I) - (0.476497 + 0.598044 I) Tanh[
            0.933024 (q - x)]) + 
       Cos[q - x] ((0.401956 + 
            0.504489 I) + (0.598044 + 0.504489 I) Tanh[
            1.06598 (q - x)])) (Sin[
         q + x] ((0.476497 - 
            0.401956 I) - (0.476497 - 0.598044 I) Tanh[
            0.933024 (q + x)]) + 
       Cos[q + x] ((0.401956 - 
            0.504489 I) + (0.598044 + 0.504489 I) Tanh[
            1.06598 (q + x)])),
    {x, -10., 10.},
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
   ],
  {q, -10., 10.},
  PlotPoints -> 10
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: timing of plot]

This timing is for the integration *and* the `Plot`, and it's less than a second.

Comment: always something i preach...that's why i appreciate you write about it (+1)

Comment: I didn't know about this "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0 trick ... works brilliantly for complicated examples where we don't want symbolic output. Any downsides that we should be aware of?

Comment: Regarding downsides, I'd say you'll be safe using this option, and I would only leave it out if `NIntegrate` throws warnings or errors, because then symbolic processing might help massage the integrand to avoid potential numerical problems.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you can integrate your function analytically.
However, if you just want to get a plot, the standard way to do so is:

```
int[qq_?NumberQ] :=
  NIntegrate[(Sin[
        q - x] ((0.476497 - 
           0.401956 I) - (0.476497 + 0.598044 I) Tanh[
           0.933024 (q - x)]) + 
      Cos[q - x] ((0.401956 + 
           0.504489 I) + (0.598044 + 0.504489 I) Tanh[
           1.06598 (q - x)])) (Sin[
        q + x] ((0.476497 - 
           0.401956 I) - (0.476497 - 0.598044 I) Tanh[
           0.933024 (q + x)]) + 
      Cos[q + x] ((0.401956 - 
           0.504489 I) + (0.598044 + 0.504489 I) Tanh[
           1.06598 (q + x)])), {x, -10., 10.}];
Plot[Re[int[q]], {q, -10., 10.}, PlotPoints -> 10] // AbsoluteTiming
```

This needs about 5 seconds.